# Taking first character of user input, discarding the rest in c

Tags: c

In my current code, If the user inputs a string not starting with c or s, it will check every character in the string, and keep outputting the printf. How would I make it so it only checks the first character and lets the user type a new string to check.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
//Declare Variables
int players, P1, P2, P3, P4, loop, loop2;
char gameType;
char c;
//Initialize Variables
players = 0;
P1 = 0;
P2 = 0;
P3 = 0;
P4 = 0;
loop = 1;
loop2 = 1;

//Figure out what game type
printf("Commander or Standard?\n"); 
gameType = getchar();
    while (loop == 1)
    {   
        if (gameType == 'C' || gameType == 'c')
        {
            P1 = 40, P2 = 40, P3 = 40, P4 = 40;
            loop = 0;   
            printf("How many players?\n");
            scanf("%s", &players);
            printf("%c players\n", players);
        }
        else if (gameType == 'S' || gameType == 's')
        {
            P1 = 20, P2 = 20;
            printf("Player 1 HP: %d\n", P1);        
            printf("Player 2 HP: %d\n", P2);
            loop = 0;                   
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("Please enter either Commander or Standard\n");
            loop = 1;
            gameType = getchar();
        }
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fgets`, then take the first character...

Comment: Oops - `scanf("%s", &players);` but you have `int players` which requires `%d` format spec.

Comment: Please don't correct the code posted in response to comments. Rolled back.

Comment: It is essential to check a function's return value for **all** user input, besides validating the value entered. Does `getchar` return `EOF` (aside: `char gameType;` should be `int gameType;`)? Does `scanf` return the numbers of successful inputs which you expect?

Comment: You also have `printf("%c players\n", players);` and again - wrong format specifier.

Comment: Sorry about the edit, didn't know. The number of players does come back correctly from what was input (after changing specifier).

Comment: The question should be edited only to clarify etc. – otherwise you will end up with perfect code that baffles why the question was asked.

Comment: If the input is multiple characters that start with either C,c,S, or S it skips the scanf statement, and prints 0 players, not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear the input at the start of your else block before the printf.

```
while ( (gameType = getchar()) != '\n' && gameType != EOF ) { }
```